# Error while installing Roracle package in Windows 32-bit

Tags: r, oracle, installation

I am trying to install Roracle in my 32-bit  windows system and I got the error mentioned below

Oracle and R have been installed.

The following path and other environment variables set

```
PATH=C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\i386;
OCI_INC=C:\Oracle\11.2.0\oci\include
OCI_LIB32=C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN
```

The command I typed in R Console
`> install.packages("ROracle",type = "source")`

The result I got

```
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ROracle_1.1-10.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 168193 bytes (164 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 164 Kb
```

```
Installing source package ROracle ...
package 'ROracle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'ROracle'
Removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/ROracle'
```

The downloaded source packages are in

```
C:\Users\sjayaraman\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSWQTi4\downloaded_packages
```

*Warning messages:*

> 1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l   "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\library"   C:\Users\SJAYAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSWQTi4/downloaded_packages/ROracle_1.1-10.tar.gz' had status 1
>   2: In install.packages("ROracle", type = "source") :
>         installation of package ‘ROracle’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 1):

Install RTools:
http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Restart R and your IDE if you're using one.